# How to implement Amazon V4 Signature for S3 via Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

iam trying to implement Amazon V4 signature for S3 via Laravel, i have gone through plenty of documentation but none working or Iam doing wrongly,  so far i have tried by adding the dependency for creating V4 [signatures](https://github.com/mfn/php-aws-post-v4-sign)

```
        $filename       = request()->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $acl            = 'private';
        $algorithm      = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
        $time           = time();
        $longdate       = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z', $time);
        $successStatus  = "201";
        $expires        = "86400";

        $accesKeyId     = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID');
        $secret         = env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'); 


                $credential = join('/', [
                    $accesKeyId, # Your AWS access key ID
                    gmdate('Ymd', $time),
                    'region',
                    's3',
                    'aws4_request',
                ]);
                # Example policy
                $policy = [
                    'expiration' => gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+2 hours', $time)),
                    'conditions' => [
                        ['acl' => $acl],
                        ['bucket' => 'sample-bucket'],
                        ['starts-with', '$key', ''],
                        ['x-amz-credential' => $credential],
                        ['x-amz-algorithm' => $algorithm],
                        ['x-amz-date' => $longdate],
                    ],
                ];

                $sigGen = new SignatureV4(
                    $secret, 
                    $policy
                );


               $signature = $sigGen->generateSignature();
```

It only creates signature for V4, i donno exactly how to send it with laravel upload request to S3, this is the code i tried to upload,

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put(
                $filename,
                file_get_contents(request()->file('file'))
              );
```

And also i have gone through the [tutorial](https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/direct-upload-to-s3-using-aws-signature-v4-php/),

That tutorial only uploading files with V4 signatures, what i need is,

- Is it possible to download, upload, delete and list files via V4
  signatures in laravel?
- Does the above mentioned tutorial is the only way to implement V4 signatures or any other way?
- Can i implement V4 with above provided code?

I donno what iam doing wrong here, pls guide me thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you’re trying to do this by hand and not just making use of the official [AWS SDK for Laravel](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel)? Also, Laravel will handle signing requests if you populate your **.env** file with your AWS credentials.

Comment: @MartinBean There is no specific reason, only for learning  purpose, is it possible? are you sure that laravel will handle signing requests? if so how to check that we using only V4 signatures? thank you.

Comment: I have used this library. You can try it - [Directo](https://github.com/kfirba/Directo)